# Using Laravel Backpack upload a file (type => upload) is not visible in editing

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I upload a file using laravel backpack **type => 'upload'** view. It uploads successfully. But in the editing, it is not visible input. What is wrong if anyone knows to help me.

**My Controller**

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'label' => "Document",
            'name' => "document",
            'type' => 'upload',
            'upload' => true,
            'crop' => false,
            'disk' => 'vault',
        ]);
```

Below I attach the edit input view. It didn't show the already uploaded file name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

Try this
use `], 'both');`

```
$this->crud->addField(
            [
             'label' => "Document",
             'name' => "document",
             'type' => 'upload',
             'upload' => true,
             'crop' => false,
             'disk' => 'vault',
            ], 'both');
```